# Suggested Post and Taxonomy structure

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I am trying to work out the most sensible way to structure a new site. I would like to have continents, countries and articles. Articles will be the normal `post` type but I am unsure of the best way to setup the continents and countries.

I have played with setting up two new post types `continent` and `country` and have added a meta box to allow the country to associate itself with a continent. The URL structure is also what I want: `/custom/continent/country`
The trouble is how to efficiently associate `posts` to a country so that they can be queried at the continent and country level.

The other option I am trying is to setup two taxonomies, which is easier in terms of categorising the posts, but makes URL rewriting a pain. I'd also want to limit the post to being tagged with multiple continents and countries.

The posts will just use a regular permalink structure for now.

**UPDATE:** *I am looking for a solution that does not use plugins please. I can already create custom post types or custom taxonomies.*

Comment: I would check out the excellent [Posts 2 Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin if you haven't already. Makes connecting posts of different types and querying them a breeze.

Comment: Thanks, I did look at that plugin but it hasn't been updated in over a year and I prefer to write my own.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the code of that plugin then and seeing how it works. The original author wrote a lot of the WP core query code and it is focused on efficiency. And regarding *I'd also want to limit the post to being tagged with multiple continents and countries*, you can use taxonomies and implement your own UI with a meta box.

Answer (score 0):

[CPTUI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) and [add_rewrite_endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) will help you get the desired things.

**[Update]** From my comment-

You need pairs for rewrite rule /base/1 or base/1/base2/2 using wordpress rewriting... and the way you want will not be that easy depending on wordpress. If you have fixed **/custom/continent/country** structure then add HTACCESS of your own as **site/1/2/3** to yield  **site/?continent=1&country=2&article=3**. This will create global variable in wordpress environment to be queried anytime... :) Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question as I want to avoid using plugins. Mainly so that I can learn, but also because I won't use 90% of the plugin functionality and want to keep the site as lightweight as possible.

Comment: You can do it without using any sort of plugin. And I can bet by the time you finish learning you will find your question very simple to answer.

Comment: I will share the answer if I figure it out myself, but I was hoping to find some help here ;)

Comment: I guess you need pairs for rewrite rule /base/1 or base/1/base/2 using wordpress rewriting... and the way you want will not be that easy depending on wordpress. If you have fixed **/custom/continent/country** structure then add HTACCESS of your own as **site/1/2/3** to yield  **site/?continent=1&country=2&article=3**. This will create global variable in wordpress environment to be queried anytime... :) Hope this helps.

Comment: That last part is actually very helpful. It would mean I could have articles nested under a continent/country/article-slug which may be nice for SEO purposes. I think I now need to focus on how to link posts to a country, and how to create templates and queries to display posts on a country page, and on a continent page. Thanks

Comment: Wordpress is SEO oriented. It is almost easy to achieve the structure you want. I guess my point is clear enough with limitation and opportunities of wordpress built-in functions (Endpoints/Rewriting) and extra effort for utilising the power of HTACCESS.

Comment: I was trying to point you to generate the code for CPT using CPT UI from some other installation, so that its arguments are clear to you.